# Genymotion won't install apk

Tags: android, apk, genymotion

I have Genymotion 2.5.4 along with VB 5.0.8 installed. Emulator works just fine, but it won't install apk downloaded inside emulator - "Can't open file" error occurs. Drag'n'drop don't work as well (I have Android SDK installed). Any thoughts?

Comment: I think you need to be more specific. What is giving you this error? Are there hints in logcat? Is it an .apk file? Have you tried other apk files? Have you checked the content of the apk file outside of the emulator?

Comment: This error occurs when I am trying to install any apk I downloaded inside the emulator. I checked trying installing Amazon Appstore, so it is fine. I tried other apk's as well - I get the same.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved this by flashing ARM - translator and GApps trough the adb. After that PlayMarket apps installed and worked just fine. Still, installing raw apk doesn't work. Although, I tried to install apk trough the File Manager and got a "App is not compatible with your device". Still open for fresh thoughts.

Comment: For anyone who has the same problem - don't run Genymotion with administrative rights. Windows policy won't allow you to drag'n'drop to higher privilege window. Launching with user privileges does the trick.